# How to Merge row into row in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

How can I Achieve this table.

From:

| TIME | DETAILS1 | DETAILS2 | DETAILS3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 | test a | test a1 | test a2 |
| 8:00 | test b | test b1 | test b2 |
| 8:00 | test c | text c1 | test c2 |

To:

| TIME | DETAILS1 | DETAILS2 | DETAILS3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 | test a | test b | test c |
|  | test a1 | test b1 | test c1 |
|  | test a2 | text b2 | test c2 |

Comment: Is this even realistic data? Do you really have "test a1" as value in field?

Comment: That would be difficult to do with a `GridView`; you'd probably have better luck using [the `ListView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Comment: Non-normalized data structure adds complication.

Comment: And if there are 4 rows, then what?

Comment: @user8077340  if your problem was solved, please don't forget to mark it as answered. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Microsoft Access, it's easier to solve this with SQL, and use this query as the datasource for your DataTable or similar class in ASP.NET later.

You also didn't provide your database structure, so I considered it being a single table named `TableTime` with columns `ID`, `Time`, `Details1`, `Details2`, and `Details3`.

This solution basically creates a ranked column (`Rank`) 'grouped' by the `Time`. So for each different `Time`, you'll get the related rows with 1, 2, 3, and so on. And the row with `Rank` equals 1 is the one you want to display the corresponding time. Every row with `Rank` greater than 1 keeps the Time empty, creating your desired effect.

You'll probably need to adapt this for your table and column names, but if you need help with that please share your table structure.

```
SELECT
    IIf([Rank]=1,[TimeTable].[Time],"") AS MyTime, 
    TimeTable.Details1, 
    TimeTable.Details2, 
    TimeTable.Details3,
    DCount("ID","TimeTable","Time = #" & [TimeTable].[Time] & "# AND ID <=" & [TimeTable].[ID]) AS Rank 
FROM TimeTable;
```

[image]